# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know how to prove the convergence (or not) of the following serie:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

$\sin^2(n) = {1 - \cos(2n) \over 2}$, so your series is $\sum_n (-1)^{n+1}({1 - \cos(2n) \over 2n})$. Since
the sum of ${(-1)^{n+1} \over n}$ converges to $\ln(2)$, it suffices to show that 
$\sum_n {(-1)^n \cos(2n) \over 2n}$ converges. This is the real part of $\sum_n {(-1)^n e^{2in} \over 2n}$.
The series $\ln(1 + z) = -\sum_n {(-1)^n z^n \over n}$ converges for all $|z| \leq 1$ other than $z = 1$
(This is pretty standard and can be shown using Dirichlet's test). Plugging in
$z = e^{2i}$ this gives that the series converges. Thus so does your original series.

Comment: I am not sure if you get full number of points if you solve the problem like this during a test.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use the [Leibniz Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) for this series because the term $\frac{\sin^2{n}}{n}$ is not monotone decreasing (Look at n = 3 and n = 4).

Intuitively, we know that $0 \leq \sin^2{n} \leq 1$, and we know something about the convergence behavior of $\sum{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}$, so it isn't completely unreasonable to expect this series to converge. Now, to actually prove its convergence...

**HINT:** Think about how you can apply [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: I am not exactly sure if Dirichlet test will be of help as it is...

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}\sin^2(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1 - \cos(2n)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\Re(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n})+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$
$$\left|\frac{1}{2}\Re(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n})+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{2}\Re(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n})\right|+\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\right|$$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\ \ \ , \ \ \ \left|\frac{1}{2}\Re(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n})\right|\leq\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n}\right|<\frac{2}{1}$$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n e^{i2n}=a_1\cdot\frac{1-r^N}{1-r},\ r=-e^{2i}=-\cos(2)-i\sin(2),\ a_1=r\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $([*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas))

Which means that the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}\sin^2(n)$ is bounded for any $N\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, so if $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}\sin^2(n)$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) is passed and that's why the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$ converges. The exact value of it is [here](http://tinyurl.com/qdbbezf).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n} \over n}:\
     {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{\mu\ \in\ \left[0,1\right)}$, let's
>   $\ds{{\cal I}\pars{\mu}
>      =\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\mu^{n}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n} \over n}}$ such that $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n} \over n} = {\cal I}\pars{1^{-}}}$ and $\ds{{\cal I}\pars{0} = 0}$:

\begin{align}
{\cal I}'\pars{\mu}&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\mu^{n - 1}\,
{1 - \cos\pars{2n} \over 2}
=\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-\mu}^{n - 1}
+ {1 \over 2\mu}\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-\mu\expo{2\ic}}^{n}
\\[3mm]&=\half\,{1 \over 1 + \mu} + {1 \over 2\mu}\,\Re\bracks{
{-\mu\expo{2\ic} \over 1 + \mu\expo{2\ic}}}
=\half\,{1 \over 1 + \mu} - \Re\bracks{{\expo{2\ic} \over 2}\,
{1 \over 1 + \mu\expo{2\ic}}}\,,\qquad{\cal I}\pars{0} = 0
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large%
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n} \over n}}=
> \int_{0}^{1^{-}}\braces{\half\,{1 \over 1 + \mu} -
> \Re\bracks{{\expo{2\ic} \over 2}\,
> {1 \over 1 + \mu\expo{2\ic}}}}\dd\mu
> \\[3mm]&=\half\bracks{%
> \ln\pars{1 + \mu} - \Re\ln\pars{1 + \mu\expo{2\ic}}}_{0}^{1^{-}}
> =\half\bracks{\ln\pars{2} - \Re\ln\pars{1 + \cos\pars{2} + \ic\sin\pars{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\bracks{\ln\pars{2}- \ln\pars{\root{2 + 2\cos\pars{2}}}}
> =\half\bracks{\ln\pars{2}- \ln\pars{\root{4\cos^{2}\pars{1}}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\bracks{\ln\pars{2}- \ln\pars{2\cos\pars{1}}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large -\,\half\,\ln\pars{\cos\pars{1}}}
> \approx 0.3078
> \end{align}

It converges !!!.

Comment: And what about convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$?